# Firebase Realtime Databse difference between data snapshots

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have a database structure like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVGfU.png) and I make a query as shown below.Is there a difference on the traffic used to download the snapshot from the database if I access each node with `snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)`  and if I don't access the nodes?

If there is no difference, is there a way to access only the keys in `Chats` without getting a snapshot data for what each key contains.I'm assuming that this way it will generate less downloaded data

```
   var requests = db.ref("Chats");
  requests.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var communicationId = snapshot.key;
    console.log("Chat id = " + communicationId);
    getMessageInfo(
      communicationId,
      function() {
        snapshot.ref.remove();
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `requests.on('child_added', ...)`, you are always going to access all of the data at the `requests` node.  It doesn't matter what you do in the callback function.  The entire node is loaded into memory, and cost of the query is paid.  What you do with the snapshot in memory doesn't cost anything else.

If you don't want all of the child nodes under `requests`, you should find some way to filter the query for only the children you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.Though I have another question,if I enable offline capabilities, will this reduce the cost of the query ?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately, explaining the specific situation.  Stack Overflow questions should be limited to a single question only, in order to be most helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned in the documentation, either of these methods can be used:

1. Call a method to get the data.
2. Set a listener to receive data-change
   events.

Traffic depends upon our usage. When your data need not get updated in realtime, you can just call a method to get the data **(1)** 
 But if you want your data to be updated in realtime, then you should go for **(2)**. When you set a listener, Firebase sends your listener an initial snapshot of the data, and then another snapshot each time the child changes.

**(1)** - Example

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/').once('value') // Single Call
```

**(2)** - Example

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/').on('child_added') // Every Update It is Called
```

And also, I think you cannot get all keys, because when you reference a child and retrieve a data, firebase itself sends it as key-value pairs (DataSnapshot).

**Further Reference:**  
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

 https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write